# Store logarithm of a variable in data set

Tags: data-mining, dataset, logarithm

I have seen many data sets where some of the variables are listed both with their original value and the logarithm of the variable.

For instance, a data set could have the variables `price`, `date`, `log(price)`. What is the reason to have a variable with the logarithm of the price? When is it useful and why storing it in data instead of just computing the logarithm when it's needed?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few reasons you may want to do this.  Just off the top of my head.

- **Efficiency.**  If the dataset is very large, computing the logarithm of every number in a column may be expensive.  Better to do it once and then store.
- **Consistency.** Why are our parameter estimates different?  Was that base $2$ or $10$?
- **Documentation.** Having the log in a column is a pretty clear indication that *this is important*.
- **System Limitations.** Believe it or not, there are some data consuming systems that *cannot* compute a logarithm.

I'm sure you can come up with more with enough thought.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. But why is the logarithm useful? In which cases?

Comment: You could write an entire library of books about that question.  : )

Comment: This site has [many highly rated questions and answers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logarithm?sort=votes&pageSize=50) about usefulness of logarithms.

Comment: Consistency and system limitations are good points. In many systems it will actually be *more* efficient to compute logs on the fly rather than to read their values from a file or database. When I think about circumstances where I have created such parallel variables, almost all involve complicated circumstances where the new variable is a logarithm *except* it requires special calculations according to the missingness codes of the original variable, or it needs to be rounded to a specific precision, etc. *Then* it can make sense to do the calculation once and for all and store the results.